# What constitutes an information leak?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

In the quantum erasure phenomenon, it is generally concluded that the wave function of probabilities collapse to a reality due to information leak. Now what exactly constitutes the information leak and what doesn't?

I don't think it is purely the human perception which amounts to information leak. How can we determine if some given hypothetical situation can produce an information leak?

Comment: *I don't think it is purely the human perception which amounts to information leak.* This is not a statement that can be scientifically proven or refuted, because science is only done by humans.

Answer (score 0):

Any detail ending up different counts as an "information leak". *Any* detail. States only interfere when they are exactly identical.

For example, if a photon flies through your experiment, gets bounced east or west depending on the spin of an electron, and then escapes... the photon's position and velocity are details that ended up different. For all intents and purposes, the electron's spin got measured.

Quantum erasers are kind of a bad example of this, because they are based on post-selection instead of on all the details being made the same again. Erasers are quite possibly the *worst* experiment to start with, if you're trying to learn and understand quantum mechanics.